Default value for components of Fortran parameterized derived types
Here is a minimal program to reproduce my problem:
program test

  use iso_fortran_env, only: REAL32

  implicit none

  type :: matrix (rows, cols, kind)
     integer, len                             :: rows
     integer, len                             :: cols
     integer, kind                            :: kind = REAL32
     real (kind=kind), dimension (rows, cols) :: values
     real (kind=kind)                         :: small = 1.0e-9
  end type matrix

end program test

When I compiled this program with gfortran 14.1, I got this error:
test.f90:12:56:

   12 |      real (kind=kind)                         :: small = 0.0e-9
      |                                                        1
Error: Cannot convert REAL(4) to REAL(0) at (1)

When I remove  = 0.0e-9, then code compiles successfully.

Did I miss something? or this is a gfortran bug?
If it is possible to initialize components of parameterized derived types like above code, how I can set type of the literal in initialization assignment (like small = 1.0e-9_kind when kind came from derived type parameters)?

EDIT:
It works with AOCC 4.1 (flang 16.0)! So I think it is gfortran bug
(similar to this bug).
So without removing the original question, I changed it to:
Considering the following parameterized derived type:
program test

  use iso_fortran_env, only: REAL32, REAL64, REAL128

  implicit none

  type :: mytype (kind)
     integer, kind    :: kind = REAL32
     real (kind=kind) :: small = 1.0e-9
  end type mytype

  type (mytype (kind=REAL32))  :: s
  type (mytype (kind=REAL64))  :: d
  type (mytype (kind=REAL128)) :: q

end program test

Here, for all real kinds (except the default real kind), the 1.0e-9 literal assigned to the small component of mytype will lose accuracy. How I can use the kind parameter in the small = 1.0e-9 default value assignment (something like small = 1.0e-9_kind)?

The parameterized derived type feature of Fortran 2018 is fairly broken in gfortran.  Unfortunately, there is currently no one looking at fixing the issues.  It is best to not use PDT with gfortran or use a different compiler such as Intel's ifx and/or ifort compilers.

@steve Fortran 2003?

@Scientist: I think it is f2003.

@steve: Thank you for your answer. I edited my question. Please read added EDIT section.

What do you think is wrong with small = 1.0e-9_kind?

@francescalus: both gfortran and flang give me error for that. I think in 1.0e-9_kind, the kind must be a integer constant (integer, parameter :: kind = REAL32 for example). Is it OK in Fortran standard? I don't have intel, nvhpc and/or pgi compilers unfortunately.

In a literal real constant like 1.0e-9_kind the kind parameter must be a named constant.
In contrast, some other specifications of kind parameter merely require a constant expression.
Within a derived type definition like
type t(kind)
   integer, kind :: kind
   real(kind) :: x=1._kind
end type

the kind parameter for the type declaration (real(kind)) is the "constant expression" requirement whereas 1._kind is the "named constant" requirement.
Within the derived type definition a kind parameter of the derived type can be used in a constant expression, but it's not a named constant. That is, we can have real(kind), but not 1._kind.
kind being a constant expression means we can, however, have
type t(kind)
   integer, kind :: kind
   real(kind) :: x=TINY(REAL(1., kind))  ! Not TINY(1._kind)
end type

You can specify the "most precise" literal constant and use kind to convert it:
type t(kind)
   integer, kind :: kind
   real(kind) :: x=REAL(1._real128, kind)
end type

but that's just
type t(kind)
   integer, kind :: kind
   real(kind) :: x=1._real128
end type

except for cases where compilers have bugs.
Note that this isn't portable: there's no guarantee that real128 is the most precise real. You're assuming it's a valid kind number, though, so whatever process you used to guarantee that you can use to guarantee it's the most precise or desirable.

I know REAL128 is not portable (I have M68K device with at most REAL80 kind). Fortran guarantees one real kind more accurate than default real kind (double precision). Actually REAL64 is sufficient for my needs. So, I have to use explicit or implicit casting from most accurate real kind. Thank you.

You may be interested to read about how you can do things differently outside literal constants and default initialization.

I read (in many places) about using integer literal kind value vs. mnemonic kinds (like 1.0_4 vs. 1.0_REAL32) that former is not portable. For example gfortran uses storage size for kind (REAL32=4, REAL64=8, REAL128=16), but processors are free to use other values. So it is better to use kind constants from iso_fortran_env or use select_real_kind. My intention to use kind as parameter to PDT, is to develop an ocean modeling library and let users to choose floating point precision (somehow generic model). I know there are other ways to do this, but I prefer this method.

1._4 is always wrong; 1._real32 is possibly wrong. Aiming for portability in Fortran (and anything else) is good, but "portability" in Fortran is widely wildly misunderstood. (I'm not saying you are wrong, but that this is a much broader topic than can have justice done in comments; I welcome further questions.)
